# Dynamically changing TaskManager interval in ExtJS 5.1.3

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have a grid that I need to update every 5 mins. For this I created an instance of Ext.util.TaskManager like

```
var task = new Ext.util.TaskManager.start({
    run: function() {
        search();
    },
    interval: 1000 * 60 * 5
});
```

This works perfectly as expected. Now I also need to add a drop down where the user can change the number of minutes they want the refresh in. Ranges from 1-5, 10, 15 mins intervals.

For this I added a combobox, a static store and a variable for the minutes and changed the above task manager function to include the variable for minutes.

```
var autoRefreshStore = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
    fields: ['value', 'text'],
    data: [
        [1, '1 min'],
        [2, '2 mins'],
        [3, '3 mins'],
        [5, '5 mins'],
        [10, '10 mins'],
        [15, '15 mins']
    ]
});

var autoRefreshIntervalInMins = 5;

//my combobox in a toolbar
{
           xtype: 'combobox',
           id: 'autoRefreshComboBox',
           fieldLabel: 'Auto Refresh Interval',
           displayField: 'text',
           valueField: 'value',
           store: autoRefreshStore,
           typeAhead: false,
           value: 5,
           editable: false,
           forceSelection: true,
           allowBlank: false,
           mode: 'local',
           width: 200,
           listeners: {
               afterrender: function(obj){
                   autoRefreshIntervalInMins = obj.getValue();
               },
               change: function(obj, newValue, oldValue, eOpts){
                   autoRefreshIntervalInMins = newValue;
               }
           }
}
var task = Ext.util.TaskManager.start({
    run: function(){
        search();
    },
    interval: 1000 * 60 * autoRefreshIntervalInMins
});
```

The problem with this is that no matter how many times I change the interval in the drop down -- the run function only runs after 5 mins -- which is the default value that I set in the `var autoRefreshIntervalInMins = 5;` The change event triggers just fine, but the task interval never changes. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try to use [singleton](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-singleton) class of ExtJS.

In **singleton** class, you can create your own function and change dynamically using get or set method.

I have created an demo Hope it will help you to solve your problem. [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/274q)

```
Ext.define('InterVal', {
    singleton: true,
    task: {
        run: function () {
            search();
        },
        interval: 1000 * 60 * 2
    },
    updateTask: function (value) {
        this.task.interval = 1000 * 60 * value;
    }
});
var autoRefreshStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['value', 'text'],
    data: [
        [1, '1 min'],
        [2, '2 mins'],
        [3, '3 mins'],
        [5, '5 mins'],
        [10, '10 mins'],
        [15, '15 mins']
    ]
});
Ext.TaskManager.start(InterVal.task);

Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Auto Refresh Interval',
    labelWidth: 'auto',
    margin: 10,
    displayField: 'text',
    valueField: 'value',
    store: autoRefreshStore,
    queryMode: 'local',
    listeners: {
        change: function (cmp, newValue) {
            Ext.TaskManager.stop(InterVal.task);
            InterVal.updateTask(newValue);
            Ext.TaskManager.start(InterVal.task);
        }
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

function search() {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Welcome to search funtion..!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer helped. Because of the way my code was already setup, I didn't have to create a singleton class. I already had a handle to the task object. So all I had to do was to change the 'change' listener to stop the task before changing the interval value and then restart the task. So the final code for the change listener would be

```
listeners: {
    change: function(obj, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
        Ext.util.TaskManager.stop(task);
        autoRefreshIntervalInMins = newValue;
        Ext.util.TaskManager.start(task);
    }
}
```

Thanks. I have accepted your answer, because it gave me a clue as to what to do.